# Form with multiple submit buttons that queries external website

Tags: javascript, forms

Hi I need to write code for a form that queries external website with three submit buttons. And each submit button will send some common input fields and some related to specific to the individual bodies. I believe I will need to use JavaScript but I am not sure what I can do about it. Below is the structure of the form.

```
<form action="external website" method="post">
{{ form_with common input selectors }}

<!-- if submit Option one is used -->
<input type="text" name="fixed" value="option one">

<!-- if submit Option two is used -->
<input type="text" name="fixed" value="option two">

<!-- if submit Option three is used -->
<input type="text" name="fixed" value="option three">

<input type="submit" name="Option one" value="option one" />
<input type="submit" name="Option two" value="option two" />
<input type="submit" name="Option three" value="option three" />
</form>
```

Any help from the experts will be appreciated!

Bests

Comment: whether the action url will differ

Comment: I did something I believe very similar to this just today at work. But I'm not sure exactly what you need to accomplish. Can you clarify?

Comment: I'll write up an example.

Comment: Have 3 forms! Much more compatible

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this will be your answer.
Simply sending one of three values as part of the form seems to be what you're asking for.

The question is fairly vague though so this may not help.

```
<!-- ONLY ONE INPUT FIELD IS NEEDED -->
<input id="SOMETHING" type="text" name="fixed" value="">


<input type="submit" name="Option one" onClick="firstbutton();" value="option one" />
<input type="submit" name="Option two" onClick="secondbutton();" value="option two" />
<input type="submit" name="Option three" onClick="thirdbutton();" value="option three" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var input1 = "whatever input 1 will be";
var input2 = "whatever input 2 will be";
var input3 = "whatever input 3 will be";
function firstbutton() {
document.getElementById('SOMETHING').value = input1;
}
function secondbutton() {
document.getElementById('SOMETHING').value = input2;
}
function thirdbutton() {
document.getElementById('SOMETHING').value = input3;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide three submits into three separate forms and give each form a different id (form1, form2, form3).  It'll be much easier.  If you hook AJAX to these form, then you wouldn't have to worry about rest of other pages linked to these forms.